# How to get rid of extra zeros at the end with datetime?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have MySQL 5.6.16 running locally and a table with a field which type is of timestamp (tried datetime as well). But every time I enter any data in it with `now()`it appears in the following format: `2014-04-14 23:23:39.000000`.

Isn't it supposed to be `2014-04-14 23:23:39`?

Even if I **manually** insert the value `2014-04-14 23:23:39` to the field it still adds the fractional seconds.

I'm clueless. Is there any way I can get rid of the extra zeros at the end?

**EDIT:** When I retrieve the value from the database with my script, the fractional seconds aren't there. Could it be that the version of myphpadmin I'm running is the cause?

Comment: Use [*datetime*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html) type for your field

Comment: I've tried that already. No difference.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html. You can set the number of fractional seconds to include. In your case that would be DATETIME(0) if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Thanks. But that still does not work for me.

Comment: What do you mean "does not work"?  What did you do?  What happened when you did that?  Please be specific.

Comment: *"The fsp value, if given, must be in the range 0 to 6. A value of 0 signifies that there is no fractional part. If omitted, the default precision is 0."* now(0). Even if I manually insert the data into the field with phpmyadmin.

Comment: Where does the data "appear" in the mentioned format: in phpMyAdmin or in your own scripts?

Comment: In my phpMyAdmin. I have not checked how it appears if I retrieve the value from the database with my script, which I'm going to try now.

Comment: When I retrieve it from the database with my PHP script and check it with var_dump, it does not contain the fractional seconds.

Comment: probably there's a default date format in phpMyAdmin which outputs it that way. If proper in your scripts - ignore.

Comment: You're not supposed to use it with the now function but instead with the datatype of your column. Thus I suggested DATETIME(0) and not NOW(0). The problem is not the function generating the value (now()) but what you are saving in your database. If you don't want the fractions change the datatype of your column. Then if you use now() it will not save the fractional seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MySQL field type should be timestamp(0) if you don't want to store the fractional seconds.

Answer (score -1):

Use `date('Y-m-d H:i:s');` while inserting.